# Error when trying to use NumbaPro's @vectorize decorator

Tags: python, numpy, jit, anaconda, numba

NumbaPro's @vectorize decorator seems like a neat way to utilize multicore processors for numeric computations. Unfortunately, the following fairly minimal example yields an error:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numbapro import vectorize, float64, int64, jit

@vectorize([float64[:](float64[:], float64, float64, int64, float64, float64[:], float64)], target='parallel')
def heat_equation(x, t, a, p, h, dxdt, pi):
    for i in xrange(p-1):
        dxdt[i] = a * (x[i-1] - 2 * x[i] + x[i+1]) / h / h
    dxdt[0] = 2*pi*np.cos(2*pi*t)
    dxdt[p-1] = 0
    return dxdt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = 200
    h = 1. / (p-1)
    a = 0.125
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, p)
    y0 = np.zeros(p)
    dxdt = np.zeros(p, dtype=np.float64)
    pi = np.pi
    for i in xrange(p):
        y0[i] = 0
    timeVector = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    solVector = odeint(heat_equation, y0, timeVector, args=(a, p, h, dxdt, pi))
    print solVector[-1, p/2]
```

The code above works just fine using the @jit decorator, but trying @vectorize gives the following error:

```
ValueError: format number 1 of "array(float64, 1d, A)" is not recognized
```

Apparently, there is an issue with the decorator parameters, but the type signature looks correct to me. Are there some additional restrictions I'm not abiding by?

Edit: modified the code to avoid use of numpy.zeros and numpy.pi within the decorated function as per Bakuriu's helpful comment below and adjusted the error received accordingly.

Comment: Actually in the examples you linked `zeros` is used **outside** the decorated function, through an explicit out parameter. You did something quite different...

Comment: So I assume the decorated function can't contain numpy.zeros calls (same apparently goes for np.pi as well). I have edited my code accordingly, changing the decorator to: `@vectorize([float64[:](float64[:], float64, float64, int64, float64, float64[:], float64)], target='parallel')` and the function definition to `def heat_equation(x, t, a, p, h, dxdt, pi)`. Unfortunately, that returns a new ValueError: `ValueError: format number 1 of "array(float64, 1d, A)" is not recognized` I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Code decorated with @jit usually cannot be directly ported to @vectorize.  @vectorize turns the decorated function into a NumPy ufunc core (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).  Additional restriction to @vectorize is that all arguments to the core function (the function being decorated) must be scalars.  Use @guvectorize if you need array arguments.  See http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/ufuncs.html#generalized-ufuncs for examples.

Comment: Using @guvectorize on this function yields a "TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not callable". Are there additional type restrictions at play here? More generally, if my goal is to use Numba/NumbaPro to parallelize that for loop in heat_equation, am I going the wrong way about it?